# How to detect mongodb reconnect failed event

Tags: mongodb

I am using nodejs mongo driver in my application. I set up below options in the connection:

```
{
  connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
  socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
  // retry to connect for 120 times
  reconnectTries: 120,
  // wait 1 second before retrying
  reconnectInterval: 1000
};
```

It will try to re-connect 120 times if the connection is broken and 1 second for each delay. I need to listen on the server status changes during re-connect. I added below event listeners:

```
db.on('close', this.onClose.bind(this));
db.on('error', this.onError.bind(this));
db.on('timeout', this.onTimeout.bind(this));
db.on('parseError', this.onParseError.bind(this));
db.on('reconnect', this.onReconnect.bind(this));
```

All the event listeners are working fine but my problem is how to detect that the `reconnect` failed after 120 times retries. For example, if the server is down then I will receive a `close` event. If the server is up during 120 seconds, I will receive `reconnect` event. But what if the server is not up in 120 seconds. How can I detect this change? Should I implement it by myself?